# Running gems rake tasks from application rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rake, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to add a rake task from a gem (geocoder https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) from a rake task of my application, as i would like it to be run just after the database is built.

So i have this code inside a rakefile

```
task :geolocal do
    spec = Gem::Specification.find_by_name 'geocoder'
    load "#{spec.gem_dir}/lib/tasks/geocoder.rake"
    puts '##################GEOCODING##############'
    Rake::Task["geocode:all CLASS=ProposedAccomodation"].execute
end
```

just following this question [Ruby Rake load tasks from a gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446153/ruby-rake-load-tasks-from-a-gem)
but i keep getting the same error

```
Don't know how to build task 'geocode:all CLASS=ProposedAccomodation'
```

any clue what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rake Execute With Multiple Arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033303/rake-execute-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: you have to pass the class as an argument to execute.

Comment: @phoet i'm trying since one hour to specify the argument, in different ways, seen in the question you linked, as well as these ones http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task, but i keep getting a 'Please specify a CLASS (model)' error. 
stuff_args = {"CLASS" => "ProposedTodo" }
This is what i'm trying last: 'Rake::Task["geocode:all"].execute(Rake::TaskArguments.new(stuff_args.keys, stuff_args.values))' any clue?

Comment: could it possibly be the uppercase name of the argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so there are several things to be taken into consideration here.

for the record, this is how you call a task with arguments

```
Rake::Task["taskname"].execute(args)
```

in your case, i did not realize first, that it actually uses environment variables instead of task arguments that are read as `ENV['CLASS']`.

that would answer your question, so you can either set it `ENV['CLASS'] = 'ClassName'` or pass it along to your call to the rake task `rake geolocal CLASS=ProposedAccomodation`.

which brings me to a following question: why are you not just calling the original rake task, there is nothing you add to it.

Comment: I see. That is actually working, to set the argument inside the task like ENV['CLASS'] = 'Class' and is what i was looking for. The advantage of doing it inside a single rake task is that i have several calls to the same task that i wanted to group together and this way it works. Thx